# How to relay data from a popup into a vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Problem**
I am opening a popup to allow users to log into a 3rd party website to get an `OAuth` token.  That login is redirecting to my Lambda function, whom I want to relay data back to the parent window and update the VueJS model with that.

**Current Attempt**
I am currently trying to use a function on the parent window and call that function, but this will only work in VueJS dev mode (I assume the access is turned off when you build and deploy?)

```
    created() {
      window.popupCallback = (userData) => {
        this.$set(this.formValues.personal, 'firstname', userData.first_name);
      }
    },
```

This is what I am returning in my lambda code to call that function.  This is what the popup redirects to after the user logged in:

```
  return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body:
      '<html><head><title>HTML from API Gateway/Lambda</title></head><body>' +
      '<script> window.opener.popupCallback(' +
      JSON.stringify(userData) +
      '); window.close();</script></body></html>',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    }
  });
```

What would ideally happen is that the Vue model would update `this.formValues.personal` with this new data (the first name).  What actually happens is in the console of the popup:

```
ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

**NOTE:** If I run the website locally and call `popupCallback()` in the browser's console that function works correctly.  When I do that after it is deployed it states that Vue is not defined.

Is there a better way to do this?  I was playing with [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel), but when I set up a listener inside of the VueJS create function it doesn't seem to work.  I assume there is an isolation going on between the browser and VueJS that I do not understand.  Any resources about this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to use [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).  It is much more suited to this problem.  It also means there are less cross-origin constraints.

Alternatively it also worked if I wrapped the `window.opener.popupCallback()` call in a try catch block since that was erroring on Vue not being defined.  I do not fully understand why that then allowed the parent window to complete the `Vue.$set` successfully.

Regardless, `postMessage()` seems like a much better approach.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `Window.postMessage()`.